# 'unresolved import discord.ext.tasks' issue

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm using **Visual Studio Community Edition** to make a discord bot. I am using `discord.py` (updated it to the last version) at the moment and whenever I use `from discord.ext import commands` I encounter following error:

> `unresolved import discord.ext.tasks`

Answer (score 0):

Check that the name of your file isn't the same as any module that you might be using. So don't name it discord.py or anything like that.